# Windows 10 does not show close/debug window any more

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

Hi I'm working on a c++ project by visual studio 2015 and windows 10 enterprise.
But I can't make windows to show close/debug window on crashes. I want to use jit debugging to find cause of crash for example I wrote this code to crash my program

```
// testvc2015.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "assert.h"

int main()
{
    char *b=0;
    b[11] = 36;
    assert(false);
    return 0;
}
```

and when I run this program in windows 10 I got this dialogue
[stop working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGskX.jpg)

then I got this dialogue and program exit without any chance for debug
[no debug button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwpwh.jpg)

I double checked the jit debugging in vs2015 and the options are set also I checked windows error reporting service and it's running.
How can I make windows to show debug button on crashes?

Comment: Please refer to [Just-In-Time Debugging in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hs4b7a6.aspx) official documentation.

Comment: I cant see any useful information in official documentation. I don't know why windows do not shows debug button

Comment: The problem might be elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying all kind of crazy ideas I disabled the windows firewall and it fixed my problem! I enabled the firewall again and its working for now.

Comment: That the reason why I suggest you close third party tool/process. Anyway, glad to know that you resolved this issue, you could mark helpful reply as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issue. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

It was not the Windows Debugger button, it was the JIT debugging button. If we want to use it, we would enable the JIT debugging.

Troubleshooting steps:

(1) Just run your VS as the **admin**, and then enable the Just-In-Time Debugging in Visual Studio, run your app again (Ctrl+F5).

(2) I also suggest you reset your VS settings, and then test it again. At least, we could know that whether it was related to the VS settings.

I test it in my VS2015 with update 3, I could get the debug button.

If still no help, I suggest you repair your VS, view the result.

[image]

Comment: I tested all of this steps but no luck. I just installed windows 10 last night. before it I was using win7 + vs 2012 for programming. This is my version of vs 2015 :Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015
Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.7.02556

Installed Version: Professional

Comment: If the default settings still has this issue,  we would think about the VS IDE or the Windows Environment. If you re-install the VS, and install the windows update, how about the result? Could you install other VS version in your machine like VS2013 or VS2017? What I know is that it will call all JIT debugging versions even if you run it just in VS2015. Maybe it is also a workaround for you to troubleshooting this issue. Please also close all third party tools or processes. If you installed any VS add-ins after you install the default VS, please also disable them, view the result.